# Why is 'updating' called when I create a new Product model?

Tags: laravel-4

I like the power of Model Events but I am sometimes puzzled by their behaviour. I have the following Handler for updating a 'last_listed' property when a product is relisted:

```
Product::updating ( function ($product) {
if ($original = $product->getOriginal ()) {
    if ((! $product->available == $original ['available']) && $product->available == "1") {
        $product->last_listed = date ( 'Y-m-d h:i:s' );
    }
}
```

} );

The `if ($original = $product->getOriginal ())` check had to be included because updating was being called even when a new Product was created. In this case there obviously was no "Original" so it safely returned false and bypassed 'updating'.

I just don't understand why it was called in the first place though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question....
Product::updating was called because I had written a Product::created handler and this of course, caused it to be invoked.